# Re-direct page when session is lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session

I am using ASP.NET.

If my sessions time out i want to re-direct the page to another URL: Say the home page....

On my page I make use of a GridView that uses Session variables. If the session variable time expire(currently at 60min) and the user click on a row in the GridView I want to re-direct him/her to the home page of my site. Can this be done, how would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you just check if session variable exists and call response.redirect to home page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store some value in Session collection. Then check if it's still there at the next user's request. If not, redirect.

// Put some session marker

```
Session["IsOldSession"] = true;
```

// Then later...

```
if (Session["IsOldSession"] == null)
    Response.Redirect ("~/OMG.aspx");
```

Comment: Typed my answer and saw this one was there! :D

Comment: Ai of course you are right, stupid me. I will add this code when the user click on the GridView SelectedIndexChanged event!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may simply rely on the the count of items in the session collection via using `Session.Contents.Count`.  I would prefer this route over instantiating an additional item to persist in the session state collection.

```
If Session.Contents.Count = 0 Then
     Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just do this in your Page_Init()

```
if (Session.IsNewSession)
{
    Response.Redirect("homepage.aspx");
}
```